# Как обнулить массив за O(1)?

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Есть массив с N элементами. Нужно обнулить все элементы в массиве. 
Естественно можно сделать цикл и обойти массив - но время затраченное на эту операцию займет O(n).

Comment: Думаю, что никак. В С++, например, есть функция `memset(void* dst, int value, size_t size);`, которая инициализирует участок памяти указанным значением. Но даже там не О(1), если углубиться в алгоритм работы этой функции. Тут ведь смотря что считать элементарной операцией...

Comment: @Vasili Anoshin, если я правильно понимаю вы не просто так говорите о ОБНУЛЕНИИ.  банальное присваивание переменной нового (пустого) массива вам не подходит?

Может вам подойдет:
`int arr = new int[1000];`

Comment: @ВиталийВихляев, думаете `new` магическим способом избегает O(n)? (если обеспечивает предоставление обнуленной памяти)

Comment: @avp а как это происходит?

Comment: @avp, я знаю про то, что это не константное время обнуления массива (нужно время на выделение памяти....)...
поэтому я и написал, что может ему простое пересоздание массива поможет... все равно за O(1)  не получится обнулить

Comment: @ВиталийВихляев использование new не подойдет, представьте что вместо нулей нужно вставить единицы. Не в этом суть.

Comment: А Array.Clear разве не за константное время работает?

Comment: @Fynivx Нужно О(1).

Comment: @VasiliAnoshin ну так, константное время это и есть O(1). Ну, естественно, не любой массив может очиститься за константное время, но они наверняка обнуляют элементы большими пачками, а не по одному. Так что, в ряде случаев должно быть ок.

Comment: @Fynivx Метод Clear получает на входе index, length  . Этот метод является операцией O(n), где n — свойство length.

Comment: @VasiliAnoshin почему? Если Вы посмотрите в исходники, то увидите, что этот метод - вызов к внешней небезопасной библиотеке. С большей вероятностью он выполняется за константное время в случаях, когда массив физически возможно очистить за O(1).

Comment: @Fynivx : алгоритм является алгоритмом постоянного времени (записывается как время O(1)), если значение T(n) ограничено значением, не зависящим от размера входа. У вас на входе массив состоящий из N элементов.

Comment: @VasiliAnoshin если Вам нужно решение для общего случая, то ответ прост - это невозможно. Ни на одном языке. Это физическое ограничение. Обнулить массив за O(1) можно только при условии, что максимальное количество элементов будет ограничено.

Answer (score 8):

Есть один читерский метод обнуления. Он ширико используется на олимпиадах. Примерный код (псевдостиль, чисто ради принципа). Для примера массив не может быть расширен (это не так важно).

```
class MyArray<T>{
     private Array<T> value;
     private Array<int> mask;
     private int current;

     public MyArray(int size){
         value = new Array<T>(size);
         mask  = new Array<int>(size);  //we hope new array fill 0. If not - fill
         current = 0;
     }  

     public  T get(int pos){
          //ToDO validate pos
          if (mask[pos] != current) 
             return null;  //or any default value for clean. 
                           //So you can "clean" different value
          return value[pos];
     }

     public void set(int pos, T val){
         //ToDO validate pos
         mask[pos] = current;
         value[pos] = val;
     }

     public void cleanAll(){
          current++;
     }

}
```

Думаю идея в дальнейшем объяснении не нуждается.

Нетрудно заметить, что время доступа по прежнему O(1). При этом "обнуление" - 1 операция.

Comment: По сути, откладывая обнуление мы переносим те же N операций "на потом" (вместе с значительными накладными расходами). Впрочем, если между "тотальными" обнулениями нам требуется доступ не ко всем, а лишь к небольшой доле элементов, то "овчинка стоит выделки".

Comment: @avp если нужен доступ ко всем элементам, то требование O(1) имеет мало смысла, а в таком виде код частенько у меня возникал) да и в системах реально времени может помочь, зря что ли в БД часто метку удалено ставят, а не реально удаляют.

Comment: @avp: можно рассматривать это реализацией copy-on-write (COW) поведения как у процессов после `fork()`  ([не стоит рассчитывать, что OS почистит память после выхода процесса](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12715229/4279)) или как [OS может одну и ту же физическую страницу в памяти с нулями подкладывать при выделении памяти](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6005003/4279) или [OS может обнулять память, когда ей заняться нечем](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538420/difference-between-malloc-and-calloc#comment1394684_1538427).

Comment: Формально говоря, вы обнулили не _массив_, а свою структуру данных.

Comment: @jfs, ага, COW отличный практический пример, в какой-то мере еще позднее связывание (RTLD_LAZY в dlopen) тут можно вспомнить.

Answer (score 2):

Время всегда будет O(n). Но вы можете обнулять массив используя несколько потоков. В Java 8 есть метод

```
Arrays.parallelSetAll()
```

Comment: м, а что в несколько потоков обнулять память получается быстрее? Есть бенчмарки?

Comment: Поддерживаю, достаточно интересный вопрос. Сильно зависит от размера массива, т.к. накладые расходы на параллельность могут перекрыть весь профит от нее.

Answer (score 2):

Обнулить за время *O(1)* можно *разряженный массив*, который обычно реализуют либо через хеш-таблицу, либо через сбалансированное дерево.

**Подробности**

Для начала попробуем абстрагироваться от *реализации* массива, и поговорим об его *интерфейсе*. В массиве хранятся однотипные элементы, доступные по целочисленным индексам. Мы можем узнать длину массива `length`, а индексы могут принимать значения от `0` до `length - 1`.

Обычно реализация массива проста: мы выделяем память подряд, достаточную, чтобы хранить `length` элементов заданного типа. Если `double` требует 8 байт, то массив из 1000 чисел двойной точности потребует 8000 байт подряд, а `i`-ый элемент будет находиться по смещению `8 * i` байт от начала.

Представим ситуацию, что наш массив достаточно большой, например, содержит миллиард элементов. 80% этих элементов имеют значение `0`. Такой массив называется *разряженным*, потому что значимых элементов в нём немного, а пустых много.

Для таких массивов жалко выделять всю память целиком, потому что большей частью она будет хранить значение по умолчанию. Мы могли бы хранить индексы и значения значимых элементов:

```
103 => 145000.3
457 => 267000.5
732 => 197500.2
```

Здесь 103, 457 и 732 — индексы значимых элементов массива, все остальные элементы равны `0.0`. Если это массив из 1000 элементов, экономия памяти налицо.

Интерфейс массива должен быть реализован следующим образом: длина массива `length` задана изначально, а список пар `индекс => значение` пуст. Операция чтения по заданному индексу должна проверять, есть ли этот индекс в списке. Если индекс есть, операция возвращает связанное значение, а если его нет, то нулевое.

Операция записи смотрит на значение. Если это значение нулевое, пара с заданным индексом должна быть удалена из списка, а если ненулевое — добавлена.

Остаётся решить вопрос эффективности поиска пары с заданным индексом. Если хранить пары в произвольном порядке, то скорость работы с таким массивом будет удручающе низкой — *O(M)* для чтения/записи элемента вместо *O(1)*. Здесь *M* — количество значимых элементов в массиве.

Пары можно организовать в двоичное дерево, тогда скорость возрастёт до `O(log N)`. Можно также воспользоваться хеш-таблицей, тогда скорость приблизится к обычному массиву `O(1)`.

Хеш-таблица это по сути внутренний массив с классической реализацией. Он содержит пары индексов и значений, и его размер для эффективной работы должен быть больше количества значимых элементов в полтора-два раза.

Конкретно: мы хотим хранить миллиард чисел двойной точности, что заняло бы 8 гигабайт оперативной памяти. Значимых чисел в этом массиве всего 5% или пятьдесят миллионов. Чтобы эффективно работать с таким количеством пар, нам нужно место для хранения ста миллионов пар. Каждая пара состоит из целого индекса (4 байта) и значения двойной точности (8 байт). Итого размер хеш-таблицы составит 1,2 гигабайта, что почти в 7 раз меньше 8-ми гигабайтов. При этом чтение и запись элемента с произвольным индексом `i` составит *O(1)*, как в классическом массиве.

Возвращаемся к главному вопросу: как очистить такой массив за время *O(1)*? Для этого нам нужно очистить внутреннюю хеш-таблицу. Это непрерывный массив, место на который мы выделили в куче. Чтобы его очистить, достаточно вернуть эту память в кучу, что можно считать операцией с фиксированным временем.

*Тут я сделаю отступление. В общем случае время может быть не фиксированным, но это тема для глубокого обсуждения. В современных средах, где работает сборка мусора, мы можем говорить о времени освобождения в пределах **O(1)**.*

Comment: за O(N)  тупым циклом можно обнулить

Comment: @Mark Shevchenko, товарищь хочет обнулить за константное O(1) время... обнуление за O(N)  - не проблема

Comment: Я думаю, что человек опечатался и имел ввиду O(1)

Comment: @АртёмОконечников Спасибо. Именно так всё и было, писал O(1), но рука дрогнула.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников можно описать поподробней что вы имеете ввиду.

Answer (score 1):

Хранить битовую маску ненулевых элементов. Для нее хранить еще одну маску и так далее. Вот только доступ (проверка на не 0) станет в O(log?(N)).

Comment: Допустим у меня старый IBMPC, где оперативная память у меня очень ограничена, и у меня для одного массива, который надо очень быстро обнулить, надо хранить в кеше кучу масок, при этом, каждое действие добавления в массив значения, будет каскадом идти по всем этим маскам, априори этот метод не очень то и хорош.